# Rspec rails on rails validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

```
validate :cannot_modify_if_locked, on: :update


def cannot_modify_if_locked
  if self.locked
    errors.add(:locked_at, "#{self.locked_at} and cannot be modified")
    false
  end
end
```

**RSPEC**

```
 consent_form = build(:consent_form, { locked_at: Date.today })
 expect(consent_form.).to eq true
```

This test is not good.
how to write this test? i need to check with rspec this validation on update

Comment: reformatted the code

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, the code is not valid. Could you please explain it in plain English inside your question?

Comment: i forogot  to write that this answer belove me helped. problem solved :) @seba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your spec you can use the `let` helper to memoize an object, which you could use to "recreate" an update which wouldn't have success, that's to say, must be invalid.

Suppose you have your model, you can create a record which will have their attributes and also the `locked` as `true`, and the `locked_at` attribute to show the date in which it was locked:

```
RSpec.describe SomeModel, type: :model do
  let(:some_object) { SomeModel.new(locked: true, locked_at: Time.now) }
```

Then you can access the object "created" with `let` and try to perform an update to it, then you can use expect to validate it won't be valid:

```
it 'invalid if object is locked' do
  some_object.update(some_atttribute: 'Some new attribute')
  expect(some_object).to_not be_valid
end
```

And also you could check for the validation error message:

```
expect(some_object.errors[:locked_at].first).to eq("#{task.locked_at} and cannot be modified")
```